# Regex not correctly replacing expected result python

Tags: python, regex

I have a dictionary of words I want to replace.

```
preprocess_pattern = {r" AND ": r" & ",
 r" O\A ": r" O/A ",
 r" D\B ": r" O/A ",
 r" D/B ": r" O/A "}

def preprocess_rules(text):

    for detect_pattern, replace_pattern in preprocess_pattern .items():
        text = re.sub(detect_pattern, replace_pattern, str(text))
        
    return text

preprocess_rules('AMAZON O\A MICROSOFT')
```

It gives me a result of 'AMAZON O\A MICROSOFT'; with two slashes(). The O\A didn't replace to O/A. Was wondering what is causing this issue.

Comment: Why use regex here if you are not using regular expressions? Do not use `re.sub`, use `.replace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\` is a metacharacter so you need to escape `detect_pattern` using [re.escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape):

```
import re

preprocess_pattern = {r" AND ": r" & ",
                      r" O\A ": r" O/A ",
                      r" D\B ": r" O/A ",
                      r" D/B ": r" O/A "}


def preprocess_rules(text):
    for detect_pattern, replace_pattern in preprocess_pattern.items():
        text = re.sub(re.escape(detect_pattern), replace_pattern, text)
    return text


res = preprocess_rules('AMAZON O\A MICROSOFT')
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
AMAZON O/A MICROSOFT
```

From the documentation:

> Escape special characters in pattern. This is useful if you want to
> match an arbitrary literal string that may have regular expression
> metacharacters in it.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Character `\` is the "escape" character in a regex. For example:

- `.` matches everything
- `\.` matches *literal* dot

Thus in your regex, you are using `O\A` which means: `O` followed by *literal* `A` and this is why it does not match/replace.

Now, to match the character `\` you need to escape it with itself! Replacing `O\A` with `O\\A` will work since it matches:

- `O`
- `\\`: literal `\`
- `A`

Note that you need to do the same for `D\B`:

```
preprocess_pattern = {
 r" AND ": r" & ",
 r" O\\A ": r" O/A ",
 r" D\\B ": r" O/A ",
 r" D/B ": r" O/A "
}
```